# I am not getting alert box

Tags: jquery

I have used a code to alert variable value on blur effect of input with id fname. Please help me with code.

```
$("#fname").blur(function() {
var childid = $("#fname").val();
$Alert(childid);

});
```

Its not showing me alert box.

Comment: After 52 questions, you are expected to know that when you get an error, you need to tell us *which one*, and in which line. -1.

Comment: folloiwing Pekka's comment: Also what is `$Alert`?

Comment: at least we should not demotivate individuals. if someone is asking a question, we must help them instead criticizing him. None here is a born expert.

Comment: @AlphaMale no one is expecting anyone to be an expert here. Just to have a *minimum* standard of quality when asking. This user has a history of asking very poor questions, and is showing zero inclination to change that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using invalid syntax for alert, try this:

```
$("#fname").blur(function() {
var childid = $("#fname").val();
 alert(childid);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 but I would sure hope you are wrong and `$Alert()` is something special the OP has added on.